# Angular - show additional div after click

Tags: angular, css, typescript

I would make some button with additional div like in the photo. Important thing is that yellow box can't move element arround. Can You help, please?

[image]

Comment: try using https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel library

Answer (score 1):

This stackblitz example accomplishes what you need.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnbzuv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML

```
<button style="float: right;" (click)="clicked()">click me</button>
  <div *ngIf="buttonClicked" style="clear:both; with:100%; text-align: center; padding:10vh; border-style: solid; border-color: yellow;">Div content here</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  buttonClicked = false;

  clicked(){
    this.buttonClicked = !this.buttonClicked;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I would have button in specific distance from right side?

Comment: I would encourage you to research basic html styling. If this answer provided the solution to your original question please mark it as such. If you require additional help please raise a new question.